# Tidy up - put things in order

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

According to [English WordNet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=tidy+up&sub=Search+WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=0), *tidy up* has a meaning:

> put (things or places) in order: "Tidy up your room!"

I feel comfortable with the use of "Tidy up your room!"

However, what is the exact meaning of *putting things in order*? Is it rather like in

1. "Tidy up your shoes!" = put all the shoes to their proper place in the shelf, do not leave any under the furniture

   or
2. "Tidy up your guitar!" = take the guitar and move it to the place where it is usually kept

In other words, can you use *tidy up* as an instruction to put one single thing to its usual place? If not, what is the best word for such a situation then?

Comment: I would interpret "tidy up your guitar" to mean get rid of excess lengths of string dangling from tuning pegs, the odd capo, and raggedy stickers half-affixed to the body. "Tidy up your shoes" likewise: get rid of the traces of chewing gum and dog-merdes adhering to the soles, and replace split laces.

Comment: I agree with Brian Donovan: to tidy **up** X is to bestow a state of order on X. To put X in its proper place and thus incorporate it in a larger state of order we say *tidy X **away***.

Comment: @StoneyB, Brian: There is *something* to that distinction, but I wouldn't put it that strongly. Here's a context where both words are (most naturally, imho) used within a single stream of invective: [*"Tidy up these toys! I cannot even walk across the room! I have asked you again and again. Get these toys tidied away **now**!"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22tidy+up+these+toys+I%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: a single instance in all of Google Books, for one of the most obvious candidates for this usage? I think that finding tends rather to support StoneyB's distinction.

Comment: @Brian: That seems like a daft thing to say. As I pointed out, I cited that one instance because it happened to include both prepositions in the same utterance. I'd say it's a racing cert most instances of *"Tidy [prep] your toys!"* would mean *"Pick up your toys and put them **away**"*. But there are actually only **5** instances of *"tidy **away** your toys"*, compared to **272** for *"tidy **up** your toys"*. To my mind the long and short of it is we usually use ***up*** irrespective of your distinction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Tidy up" suggests that there is a state of perceived organizational disorder among some set of objects relative to a broader context, but not necessarily in relation to the objects themselves.  In the classic example of tidying up one's room, the judgment is that objects in the room are in some perceived state of disarray relative to the perceiver's expectation for the state and purpose of the room.  Rarely, if ever, would one hear of a need to "tidy up" a junkyard.  This is because the perceived purpose of that place does not include an expectation that the objects be in order to serve the place's purpose or meet the typical person's expectations for it.

All that said, one cannot "tidy up" a single object in a given context since it has no other objects in its given context.  For example, if a room (the context) has one object in it, the room can't be "tidied up" because in order for it to be in organizational disarray, there has to be other objects in it to create a state of measurable organization.

But as one commenter has written, one can refer to a non-atomic object (such as a guitar with strings) as the context in the phrase that includes the verb "to tidy up" in some way.  The strings on the guitar need to be tidied up, for example, but it's in relation to the guitar and its perceived purpose, not to the other strings on it.  So while a guitar is not a room, it might still need "tidying up" in some way by someone's standards.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

In the quoted definition of *[tidy up](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=tidy+up&sub=Search+WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=0)*, 
*[order](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/order#Noun)* is used in the following sense:

> The state of being well arranged. [eg]  The house is in order; the machinery is out of order.

Another sense of *order* is closely related:

> Conformity with law or decorum; freedom from disturbance; general tranquillity; public quiet. [eg] to preserve order in a community or an assembly

The sense of *[order](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/order#Verb)* suggested in the question – that of placing things into sequence according to some rule of precedence – is not relevant to *order* as used in the quoted definition of *tidy up*.